# Expo.launchCameraAsync custom image view?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am creating camera feature for my app so that after the user takes the photo, they can rescale and move it around a bounding box. `Expo` have an out of box API that does what I want:

```
ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({ allowsEditing: true, aspect: [4,3] })
```

but I would also like the camera screen itself to be full screen, so no black bars on top and bottom, I have the view here:

```
import { ImagePicker, Camera, Permissions, FileSystem } from 'expo';

    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Camera 
            style = {{ flex: 1 }} 
            type  = {this.state.type}
            ref   = {ref => { this.camera = ref }} 
        >
            <View style={camera.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    style = {this.state.css.touchable}
                    onPress={this.onTap}
                />

                <Button transparent
                    onPress = {this.onSnapShot}
                    style   = {[camera.buttonContainer, this.state.css.button]}
                >
                    <Entypo 
                        name  = 'circle' 
                        size  = {fonts.camera} 
                        color = {colors.wineWhite}
                    />
                </Button>
            </View>
        </Camera>
    </View>
```

The detail isn't important, the point is that I can create a `Camera` view. Now the question is is there a way to pass in this camera view into `launchCameraAsync`? The documentation does not seem to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this combinition is not possible.

`ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({ allowsEditing: true, aspect: [4,3] })` is calling a full capsuled expo component.

If you want to create a customized view, you have to handle all states and video/photo actions by you're own.

Answer (score 1):

Try launching an [ImageManipulator](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/sdk/imagemanipulator) after the picture is taken. After calling takePictureAsync, wait for the promise to resolve, then you'll get the local uri of the image, being able to pass that to the ImageManipulator.

Comment: could you give an example with resize? The example does not really have the kind of pinch-zoom and drag to slide effect I'm looking for. And I"m hoping to not use an external library if possible, since they always require more integration work

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems I misread the documentation. The ImagePicker API has an built-in editor, which I though would be included in the ImageManipulator. However, it seems like if you really want to have a custom camera, you'll have to build your own implementation of an image editor. However, that shouldn't be that hard. I would recommend you take a look at [react-native-gesture-handler](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html), which implements rotations and pinches, and is included with Expo.

Comment: Use those kinds of animations to transform an <Image />, and save the modifications the user did to it. Then, when the user actually wants to save it, pass the resize/rotate/crop properties to the ImageManipulator, and you'll get a new modified image.